# Remove Column from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a database that has a Users table and I present the data in a DataGridView. I would like to remove 4 columns, but the code I have (referenced from MSDN) seems to append the columns at the end. How can I totally REMOVE the columns?

So this is how the DGV looks without the columns removed

[image: Without Removal Code]

The Code I use to TRY and remove the columns

```
RadarServerEntities rse = new RadarServerEntities();
gvUsers.DataSource = rse.Users;

gvUsers.Columns.Remove("ID");
gvUsers.Columns.Remove("InsertDate");
gvUsers.Columns.Remove("Connections");
gvUsers.Columns.Remove("MachineID");
```

The result

[image: With Removal Code]

I would like to get rid of the last 4 columns, so why isnt my code doing it?

Many Thanks :)

Comment: Have your tried hiding them instead: `gvUsers.Columns["ID"].Visible = false`?

Comment: I find that `gvUsers.Columns.Remove("ID");` works.. if the column name (not heading/text), but the column name is ID.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tend to just hide the fields instead.

```
gvUsers.Columns["ID"].Visibility = false;
```

Et cetera.

Comment: Actually its `gvUsers.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;`

Comment: why would it be that that  `gvUsers.Columns["ID"].Visibility = false;` (presumably) works for him but `gvUsers.Columns.Remove("ID");` isn't working for him?

Answer (score 8):

you could also use `gvUsers.Columns.RemoveAt(IndexOfColumn);`

Comment: @War10ck can you explain why it doesn't answer the question? it looks to me rather like the questioner asked how to remove columns and the answerer gave what looks like what would remove columns.. in which case this answers it more than the accepted answer that just spoke of visibility. So how is it that this doesn't answer the question?

Answer (score 7):

if you don't want to create the columns automatically when you bind your `DataSource`, you need to set `gvUsers.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

```
RadarServerEntities rse = new RadarServerEntities();
gvUsers.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
gvUsers.DataSource = rse.Users;
```

Comment: I want it to automatically create the columns, but remove the ones I dont need.

Answer (score 6):

To actually remove automatically generated column you have to turn off automatic generation after data binding.

So the code would be:

```
RadarServerEntities rse = new RadarServerEntities();
gvUsers.DataSource = rse.Users;
gvUsers.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
gvUsers.Columns.Remove("ID");
gvUsers.Columns.Remove("InsertDate");
gvUsers.Columns.Remove("Connections");
gvUsers.Columns.Remove("MachineID");
```

I haven't checked what exactly happens, but probably the moment DGV becomes visible, missing columns are re-autogenerated.

So with this solution you have columns generated at the moment of binding data, then you turn it off and remove columns that you don't need. Missing columns can't be re-generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewColumn DataGridViewColumnSelected;   
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
                    if (e.ColumnIndex !=-1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
                    {
                        DataGridViewColumnSelected = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewColumn;

                    }
}

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            bool bHandled = false;
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Delete:
                    if (DataGridViewColumnSelected != null)
                    {
                        this.dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(DataGridViewColumnSelected.Index);
                        //dataGridView1.Columns[DataGridViewColumnSelected.Name].Visible = false;  // case of just hiding the column
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return bHandled;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to Modify DataTable before passing it to DGV

as follow:

```
RadarServerEntities rse = new RadarServerEntities();
rse.Users.Columns.Remove("ID");
rse.Users.Columns.Remove("InsertDate");
rse.Users.Columns.Remove("Connections");
rse.Users.Columns.Remove("MachineID");
dgvUsers.DataSource=rse.Users;
```

this method worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Old post but the real answer is [Soul Reaver's] answer. Setting `Visible = true` doesn't remove it, just hides it. So `dataGridView.Columns.Remove("columnToRemove");` is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to remove from a `DataGridView` is the column you have selected then this code is for you.

Place this code in the delete button and ready to delete the column you have selected.

```cs
int rowIndex = TuDataGrigView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
TuDataGrigView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
```